# Scaling to sceen using libgdx on Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm creating a simple game for Android using libgdx. I've come to the issue of having different screen sizes for different devices yet haven't found any concreted documentation on how to deal with this problem.

I think I'm supposed to use an `OrthographicCamera`? An example of code I have so far is:

```
private OrthographicCamera camera;

public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/cube.png"));
        texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(1280, 720);

        sprite = new Sprite(texture);
        sprite.setOrigin(0, 0);
        sprite.setPosition(1280/2, 600);
}

public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.204f, 0.255f, 0.255f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        sprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();

}
```

Am I going along the right lines? I don't have any other devices to test on and my emulators are causing me issues.

Comment: You don't need other devices to test different sizes. As long as you update your camera in the resize method, either with the new Viewport classes or manually, you can just resize the window in your desktop build.

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't already do so, you should upgrade your LibGDX version to the latest release which is 1.0.0. In this version the socalled `Viewport` has been introduced.

You can find some screenshots and code snippets and everything you need to know [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports).

Basically you will have to decide for a certain strategy (your question sounds like you are interesting in either `ScreenViewport` or `StretchViewport`) and then let that manage your camera.

Comment: I've just recently installed libgdx actually, I think I have 1.0.0. How would I check the version?

Comment: Check if the `Viewport` class exists, or not.

Answer (score 0):

What I use in my libGDX projects is to `override` the `resize` method and set the `OrthographicCamera` to the size of the screen as follows, using the built in method called `setToOrtho(boolean yDown)` which sets camera centered on the current size which a parameter if you want the y-Axis pointing down or not:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height){
    camera.setToOrtho(false);
}
```

This, however will not change the size of your textures if you want to rescale your textures as well then I would recommend rather than setting them to an absolute size e.g 15 pixels try setting them to a percentage of the screen size.

Or, another, sometimes more effective method is to work out the correct sizes at a certain size e.g 800 x 480 then work out the percentage increase in width and apply that to your sprites E.g:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height){
    super.resize(width, height);
    camera.setToOrtho(false);

    //The following is if the sprites are normally correct scaled
    //for a screen size of 800 x 480, change to whatever you need
    //They should both be floats and class variables

    widthChange = width / 800;
    heightChange = height / 480;
}

public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.204f, 0.255f, 0.255f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    //Rather than using sprite.draw(batch), use:
    batch.draw(sprite, sprite.x * widthChange, sprite.y * heightChange, sprite.width * widthChange, sprite.height * heightChange);

    batch.end();

}
```